# Netbeans 8.2 PHP autocomplete for objects stored in variables inherited from parent class does not work

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans-8, fat-free-framework

Good day!

I have question about code auto completion in Netbeans PHP 8.2 X64, running on Windows 10. I have a class which is to be extended:

```
class Controller {

    protected $obj;

    public function __construct() {
        /* @var obj DataValidator */
        $this->obj = DataValidator::instance();
    }

}
```

If I extend the class in the same file, autocomplete works for $this->obj.

```
class BazController extends Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function doSomething(){
        $this->obj->doSomething() //autocomplete works!
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot - its working!]

If I create a new file, it does not work. Netbeans knows the $this->obj, but does not show not the methods $this->obj.

```
class BarController extends Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function doSomething(){
        /* @var this->obj DataValidator */
        $this->obj-> // autocomplete does not work
    }

}
```

[image: Not working]

I would really like to use autocomplete and it works most of the time, but not when doing this. Perhaps other people solved this already (and I was not able to find it?)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. You need to add the following to your file to make it work:

```
@propery CLASS $varname
```

So it looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of FooController
 *
 * @property \DataValidator $dv
 * @property \Base $f3
 * @property \SQL $db
 */

class BazController extends Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function doSomething(){
        /** @var $dv \DataValidator */
        $this->f3->
    }

}
```

Then, the autocompletion for $this-> will work, as shown in the picture below:
[image: Working now..]

Answer (score 1):

maybe put the doc hint on the class property directly:

```
/** @var \DataValidator */
protected $obj;
```

Comment: I've tried that - no luck. Still no autocomplete of $this->   in the extending class if saved in a seperate file.

Comment: then use PhpStorm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have USE statement at the begining of the file ?

use ......./Controller;

Comment: No. Added it and tried again  - unfortunately, no autocomplete for $this->dv (or the others).